# Append xml document to bottom of existing xml doc

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml document and want to append another xml at the bottom of it. Using the xml classes in .NET, what is the quickest way to do this (in 3.5)?

Thanks

Comment: I tried a number of things which worked with nodes etc, but Jon's suggestion (below) is much more readable and obvious in intent.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest as in most efficient, or quickest as in simplest? For example:

```
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(...);
XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(...);

// Copy the root element of doc2 to the end of doc1
doc1.Root.Add(doc2.Root);
doc1.Save(...);
```

Alternatively, you *may* want:

```
// Copy the *contents* of the root element of doc2 to the end of doc1
doc1.Root.Add(doc2.Root.Descendants());
```

If you can be more precise about your requirements, we may be able to help more. Note that an XML document can only have one root element, so you can't just put one document after another.

Comment: I meant efficiency wise, but that is an elegant solution.

Comment: @dotnetdev: So try that, and see whether it's efficient enough for what you want to do. Don't start writing more efficient but less readable code before you've tested the simple version.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you will be able to do this using the XML classes.  XML libraries typically aim to protect you from creating poorly-formed XML, and the concatenation of two XML documents will be poorly formed because the document node will have two child elements.

If the .Net libraries do allow you to do this, I suggest you raise it as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.AppendChild(...);
xml.PrependChild(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to add a second root node the fastest way would be to read the first file line by line and add it to the second file. That's a very dirty way and you'll get an **invalid** xml file!

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file1 = System.IO.File.AppendText(path);
System.IO.StreamReader file2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(path2)

while(!file2.EndOfStream)
{
    file1.WriteLine(file2.ReadLine());
}

file1.Close();
file2.Close();
```

I even don't like this solution!